# xamarin.Forms - or Specific platform UI -

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

I'm need to build application with next design
Application design [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eaTR4.png)

The 3 pages - its main pages and must can be switch like carousel - but while switching - I need to mark active tab (for example set under text line with color and do bigger icon)

Also I need show master page.
I'm really junior in Xamarin - so please give me tips - what are pages type I need to apply ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

From your desing, I can see the following page and view types:

1. Tabbed page - https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/user-interface/navigation/tabbed-page/
2. master-detail-page for the master page - https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/user-interface/navigation/master-detail-page/
3. ContentPage for the right most page - https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Xamarin.Forms.ContentPage/
4. Button - for the button with the animation you will probably have to use a custom renderer - https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/custom-renderer/view/
5. ListView for the lists - https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/user-interface/listview/